# How to uses two member functions sequentially on a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, maps, base-class, pointer-to-member

I am having some trouble using two memeber functions on a base class pointer. I have the following code;

```
    cout << "Please input the translation vector. (x value ' ' y value)" << endl;
    cin >> Xtrans >> Ytrans; 
    cout << endl;
    new_shape = Trans + user_input;  // adds Tranaslated to the key

    for(it = shape_map.begin(); it != shape_map.end(); ++it){// loops over map (it is defined earlier)
        cout << endl;
        if( it->first == user_input){
        cout << "ID " << new_shape << " = " << endl;  // ouput the key witch also id's the shape
        it->second->translate(matrix(Xtrans, Ytrans))->printshape(); //<-this one
        }
    }
```

The purpose of the code is to translate a shape (I have different classes for several types that are derived from an abstract base class called polygon) and then print the new shape. I have a translate and a print function that work separately but when I combine them the code runs but crashes when it gets to the marked line.

When I debug the code a line in my translate function is highlighted.

Is this the right way to combine two functions? Should I have some intermediate step?

MORE INFO

shape_map is `<string, polygon*>`

when I do,`it->second->printshape();` or `it->second->translate(matrix(Xtrans, Ytrans);` it doesn't crash and prints the original shape but I don't know if translate works.

Comment: What's the signature of  `translate`? What does it return? (Seeing the actual code might help.)

Comment: Please show a few lines from `translate()` - it's signature, the declaration of its return value inside the function, and the `return` line.

Comment: Yeah sorry, translate returns a class derived from polygon. This is how I have defined it in polygon `virtual polygon *translate(class matrix &m) = 0;` and this the translate function for a rectangle `vector<matrix> trans_vertices;
  for (auto i = vertices.begin(); i != vertices.end(); i++){
   trans_vertices.push_back(*i+m);
  }
  
  double transCx, transCy;
  transCx = centrex + m.getx();
  transCy = centrey + m.gety();
  return new Rectangle(transCx, transCy, trans_vertices);
 }`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. The problem highlighted from debugging seems to be the `+ m.gety()` bit as it goes back to a `gety()` function in another class I use to store the points as a matrix (1x2). The `gety()` function is `double matrix::gety(){
     return coords[1];
         }`